# GUI wait for user input and do something if time runs out

Tags: matlab

I am working with a script that takes user input. I want the user to answer on the input within 4 seconds otherwise the code shall do something (right now without using a GUI). What I have done so far is to start a `tic` and prompt a input `testInput = input('Enter the number: ');` Meanwhile the prompt is open (waiting for input) I am checking if time has not runed out:

`elapsed_time = toc;
if elapsed_time > 4
    %do something
end`

To the problem:
From what I have learned, there's no way to programmatically terminate a running command in MATLAB, or even let the code do something while the prompt is open. Therefore I can not check if 4 sec has passed **before** the user inputs something. I've read ([here](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96229-how-can-i-have-a-dialog-box-or-user-prompt-with-a-time-out-period?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)) that this might be possible to solve by using a GUI. I have although no idea how to implement this, since I am totally new.

So, would this be possible with a GUI? Because with the command window it is not.

I would really appreciate to see how something simple like this could look like as a GUI (just something very simple, a window with a input box):

```
%Start a time ticker
tic;

testInput = input('Enter the number: ');

elapsed_time = toc;

 if elapsed_time > 4
    %do something
 end
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Do you want not to keep waiting for input if 4 sec are passed?

Comment: Nothing more than that when the prompt is waiting for user input, it is not possible to show things in the command window, play a sound or whatever until the user makes an input and press enter, that is the problem.

Comment: So is the answer to my question "yes"?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama No, what I want to do is to basically terminate the inputdlg once time runs out.

Comment: The thing is that the code shall do something once time runs out, but this is prevented due to the open inputdlg or prompt.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Its not different, I misunderstood you. The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: ***1.*** I don't believe GUI is anything that would give you any extra option like the one you mentioned.   ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ***2.*** The link you mentioned does not say anything like it's possible with only GUI and not with *command window*!  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ***3.*** If using GUI is not necessary for you, why are you even asking for that?  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ***4.*** Did you even try the answer given in that link? Because that answer does exactly what you want (and also has the GUI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example of a custom GUI where the user should enter a number before a maximum time is reached. Please read some about [callbacks](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html), [handles](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guihandles.html), [figure options](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html) and [uicontrol](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) to better understand it.

Note that you might need to do som more fault handling of the input string (check that number is valid)

```
function EnterNumber()

% Create figure
inDlg = figure('NumberTitle','off','MenuBar','none','ToolBar','none');

% Create timer, set it to run TimerFcn after 4 s
maxTime = 4;
tH = timer('TimerFcn', {@closeFig inDlg}, 'StartDelay', maxTime);

% Create text and input box for number in figure
uicontrol(inDlg,...
    'Style','Text','FontSize',14, ...
    'String',sprintf('Please enter a number within %d seconds:', maxTime),...
    'Units','Normalized','Position',[0.1 0.6 0.8 0.2]);
editBox = uicontrol(inDlg,...
    'Style','Edit','Units','Normalized','Position',[0.1 0.5 0.8 0.2], ...
    'FontSize',14,'Callback',@returnEditValue);

% Start timer
start(tH);

% Set focus on the edit box so a number could be entered instantly
uicontrol(editBox)

% Wait for figure to be closed (in any way)
waitfor(inDlg)
fprintf('Moving on ...\n');


% Callback function to save number
function returnEditValue(hObject,~)
% Get the number
number = str2double(get(hObject,'String'));
% Example of how to display the number
fprintf('The entered number is %d\n', number);
% Example of saving the number to workspace
assignin('base','number', number); 
% Close figure
close(get(hObject,'Parent')); 


% Calback function for timer timeout
function closeFig(~,~,figH)
% If figure exist, close it
if ishandle(figH)
    close(figH)
    fprintf('Too slow!\n')
end
```